# ¿Cómo puedo abrir las herramientas para desarrolladores usando Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Al pulsar un botón ¿cómo puedo abrir herramientas para desarrolladores?

```html
<button onclick="abrirherramientas()"></button>
```

Comment: Deberias probar a crear un evento oyente para escuchar la tecla `F12` o simularla. si, mas bien simular el presionado de esa tecla mediante tu funcion, ten en cuenta que para poder que esto ocurra debe ocurrir un `action performed`,  es decir, una accion que haya ocurrido mediante los perifericos del usuario, por lo tanto no puedes abrir las herramientas de desarrollo sin que el usuario haya dado click o haya pulsado una tecla por ejemplo (el navegador bloquearia esta accion). a menos claro de que use un periferico que accione esa funcion, por ejemplo el mouse o la mismisima tecla `F12`.

Answer (score 0):

Según leo en: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=112277

"We only allow explicit devtools opening." por lo que entiendo que no es posible abrir mediante ningún otro método que no sea manualmente.